# The relations between some 3-components links and trefoil knots

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, surgery-theory

It is intuitive to see that the 3-components links (under Alexander–Briggs notations) $6^3_1, 6^3_2, 6^3_3$ are closely related to each other; in a sense by doing a cut-gluing or sew-gluing surgery, we can transform one to the others.

[image]

Similarly, one can also do the surgery to transform $6^3_1, 6^3_2, 6^3_3$ to $3_1$ trefoil knots.  This surgery is especially intuitive from $6^3_2$ to $3_1$.

[image]

> So my question is that what is the mathematical procedure to formulate this surgery? Are those procedures fully captured by Reidemeister moves? And what are the explicit math relations to transform $6^3_1, 6^3_2, 6^3_3$, $3_1$ to each other?

For example, one can write direct sums of Hopf links as $2^2_1\# 2^2_1$ to form a new 3-component non-prime links. it may be the easiest one in the case of 
$$6^3_2 \to 3_1.$$ 
There should be also some considerations of orientations and framing for the others:
$$6^3_1 \to 3_1,$$
$$6^3_3 \to 3_1.$$

p.s. It will be greatly appreciated that if someone please makes the statement explicitly and as simple as possible. (excuse me, I am a physicist.) Thank you.

Comment: I think the relation is more natural in high dimensions.  For example, there is a non-trivial 3-component link $\sqcup_3 S^3 \to S^6$ which when you take the connect-sum of all three components gives you the simplest non-trivial smooth embedding $S^3 \to S^6$.  This is an old result of Haefliger's.

Comment: Indeed Ryan, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763496/the-knot-surgery-from-a-63-2-knot-to-a-3-1-trefoil-knot

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted on MSE.

Comment: If I delete the post at MSE, does that resolve the off-topic issue? (That post is a simpler version of that MSE question. So these twos are not exactly the same.) Or maybe it does not matter because no one will attempt to answer this question? Or shall I close this MO post myself?

Comment: Dear @Idear: I don't know whether this question would be accepted if it had not been asked at Math.StackExchange. I voted to close because simultaneous posting of questions on multiple sites leads to duplication of effort. It is better to pick one site for your question and wait at least a few days for an answer.